# Pycharm edit a file in a tab opened with ansible-vault

Tags: pycharm, external-tools, ansible-vault

I have ansible files that are encrypted using **ansible-vault**. I want to decrypt, edit, and save encrypted these files from within an IDEA IDE, in this case, pycharm.

I have created an external tool in pycharm that will decrypt the files and open them in a run window in the IDE in what appears to be a tmp file. I need the output of the tool to be placed in an edit tab and save it to same file.

Here is how I created the external tool:

**Preferences -> External Tools -> New**

```
Name: Vault Edit
Group: Ansible
Options: Synchronise files after execution, Open console
Show in: Main menu, Editor Menu
Tool Settings:
  Programs: /path/to/vault_edit.sh
  Parameters: edit $FileName$
  workding directory: $FileDir$
```

**vault_edit.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

EDITOR=charm
ansible-vault --vault-password-file=~/.vault/vault_password.txt "$@"
```

The `run` window is showing the decrypted output, but it of course is not allowing me to edit the file, let alone save it. I can't find any documentation on how to push the output of the ansible-vault to a tabbed edit window in pycharm.

It is showing output like:

```
/path/to/vault_edit.sh edit hosts
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

If I can get this working, I plan on doing something similar to allow for encryption of a file as well.